# In Angular 2, is it possible to fadeIn / fadeout instead of [hidden='xxx]?

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, is it possible to fadeIn / fadeout instead of [hidden='xxx]?

I have snippet of

```
<div  [hidden]="visible">
```

and want it to fade out on visible change...

tx

Sean

Comment: Animations are not part of A2 yet: "Animations - A forthcoming animation library makes it easy for developers to animate component behavior without deep knowledge of animation techniques or css." -- [dev guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html)

Comment: yes I know, but wanted to see if someone had a hack for now...

Answer (score 43):

Sorry I'm a little late to the party on this one.

This is a super easy way to do it and I've implemented this in my application. Use CSS3 animations by adding and subtracting classes.

First in your component css file:

```
.show{
opacity: 1 !important;
}
.step{
opacity: 0;
transition: .5s ease-in-out all;
}
```

Next, conditionally add your class to an element.

```
<div [class.show]="!booleanFromComponentClass" class="step">
  <h4>All of these elements will be faded out using a CSS3 opacity transition.</h4>
  <div>
     this element will fade out also when the booleanFromComponentClass variable is false
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also take advantage of any property including making an element's position relative and animating a slide off of the page.

If Angular2 ever implements animations, I can guarantee they are using CSS3 animations by conditionally adding and subtracting classes.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: The problem with this is that that div is just hidden, instead of being "display: none" and being completely removed from the structure of the page

Comment: @labago you can solve that issue by using `position:absolute` on the hidden div/container, and tweaking the location accordingly

Comment: in the component class file?  so you would need to write this again for every component! the css cannot live in the styles css file?

Answer (score 23):

If anyone come here to find angular solution to do the stuff, here you go

In html template

```html
<a (click)="toggle()">toggle state</a>

<div [@visibilityChanged]="visiblityState" >    
   some content
</div>
```

In component

```js
    //other imports..
    import { trigger, state, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

    @Component({
      selector: 'some-selector',
      templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
      animations: [
        trigger('visibilityChanged', [
          state('shown', style({ opacity: 1 })),
          state('hidden', style({ opacity: 0 })),
          transition('shown => hidden', animate('600ms')),
          transition('hidden => shown', animate('300ms')),
        ])
      ]
    })
    export class MyComponent {
      visiblityState = 'hidden';
      toggle() {
        if (this.visiblityState === 'hidden')
          this.visiblityState = 'shown';
        else
          this.visiblityState = 'hidden';
      }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget import { trigger, state, transition, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';

Comment: Thanks @DiamondDrake, the import statement was missing! updated the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Css only solution. Add class 'step' and [class.show]="fadeInIfTrue" to block you want to fade.

css:

```
.step {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;

  &.show {
    display: block;
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    animation: anim .7s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .7s ease-in-out all;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

source - https://jdsteinbach.com/css/snippet-animate-display-transform/

Answer (score -3):

after some digging found the answer, you need to use the Browser Adapter interface in ng2

```
import {Component, ViewContainerRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

export class Filemenu {


   private visible:boolean;
    el:any;
    wrapper:any;
    bar:any;
    viewContainer:ViewContainerRef;
    dom = new BrowserDomAdapter();

    constructor(viewContainer:ViewContainerRef) {
        this.viewContainer = viewContainer;
        this.el = viewContainer.element.nativeElement;
        let bar = this.dom.getElementsByTagName(this.el, 'div')[0];
        $(bar).fadeOut(3000, () => {
            //notify ng2 of the changes so we comply with the framework
             this.dom.setStyle(this.el, 'opacity', '0');
        });
         ...
```

and how cool is that, we can still use jQuery as long as we remember to notify the framework of our changes...

hope it helps others.

regards

Sean

Comment: You don't want to use jQuery, as it ties you directly to the DOM. You want to use the BrowserDomAdapter to manipulate the DOM, so that your app can be run in environments without direct access to a DOM. Read the warning here for more info: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ElementRef-class.html

Answer (score -10):

```
 this.userName.valueChanges.debounceTime(100).subscribe(
        (value:string) => {
            console.log('name changed, notified via observable: ', value);
        }
    );
```