# Can't make CSS Animation work properly with visibility change

Tags: html, css, angular7, css-animations

I'm trying to use an animation on visibility change but it's not working correctly.
Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45838232/4116960), I've added an animation for visibility change for the rows of a mat table. This is my table:

```
<ng-container>
    <mat-card class="mat-card py-0">
        <mat-card-header class="label">
          <ng-container>
            <mat-card-title>{{titoloTabella}}</mat-card-title> 
            <button mat-button class="align-right" (click)="changeClass()">
              <mat-icon [ngClass]="(rotate)?'rotate':'no-rotate'">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </ng-container>
          </mat-card-header>
  <table mat-table  matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" matTableExporter #exporter="matTableExporter">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let header of tableConfiguration.tableHeaders; let i = index" matColumnDef="{{ header.headerId }}"> 
      <th mat-header-cell mat-sort-header *matHeaderCellDef>{{ header.headerName }}</th>

      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" > {{ row[header.headerId] }} </td> 

      <ng-container *ngIf="i == 0 && header.isJoinable == 'no'">
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>TOTALE</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="i > 0">    
          <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ tableFooter[header.headerId] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" [ngClass]="(collapsed)? 'collapsed-rows': 'no-collapsed-rows' " [@visibilityChanged]="visibilityState"></tr>
    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  </table>
</mat-card>
</ng-container>
```

When the button containing the icon is clicked, I change the visibility of the rows by changing their class. CSS classes are:

```
.collapsed-rows {
    visibility: collapse; 
 }

.no-collapsed-rows{
   visibility: visible;
  }
```

Then in my .ts I have:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-report-table',
  templateUrl: './report-table.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
      state('visible', style({ opacity: 1 })),
      state('collapse', style({ opacity: 0 })),
      transition('visible => collapse', animate('600ms')),
      transition('collapse => visible', animate('300ms')),
    ])
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./report-table.component.scss']
})
[...]
 changeClass(){
    this.rotate = !this.rotate;
    this.collapsed = !this.collapsed;
    if (this.visibilityState === 'collapse')
          this.visibilityState = 'visible';
        else
          this.visibilityState = 'collapse';
      }
```

The rows correctly fade when they appear (so when visibility returns visible), but when their visibility change back to "collapse" they disappear instantly without fading. What did I miss?

Comment: Visibility is sort of binary, it is applied immediately and can not be quantified for animation to work. So opacity change is animated on element, which is not visible immediately on hide animation start. You may change visibility state after animation is complete.

Comment: @SergiyT. how can I achieve this? Would be enough to change `transition('visible => collapse', animate('600ms'))` to `transition(animate('600ms'), 'visible => collapse')` ?

Comment: I do not have extensive experience with angular7 but perhaps you can use done animation callback like described here: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3219-using-animation-callbacks-when-animation-transitions-are-interrupted-in-angular-2-4-4.htm